Which correlation coefficient does Excel's CORREL() compute?
Which correlation coefficient does Excel's CORREL() compute? Is it Pearson correlation, Spearman correlation, or something else?  The official doc doesn't say.

I would say Pearson as the formula on that page looks the same as what you can find on the Pearson's Correlation page on wikipedia.

I know Wikipedia is not the best but see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#:~:text=Excel%20has%20an%20in%2Dbuilt%20correl(array1%2C%20array2)%20function%20for%20calculating%20the%20pearson%27s%20correlation%20coefficient.

Pearson, same as analysis toolpak. https://www.flexyourdata.com/blog/excel-lambda-correlmatrix-calculate-a-correlation-coefficient-matrix-in-excel/

Excel's correl() function computes Pearson's correlation coefficient.
Official doc:



which matches Pearson's correlation coefficient:



